# python: how to keep a row of an array in one line, when write a json to a file

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary object whose content is:

```
{
  "A" : {
    "B" : {
      "C" : [
        [ 1000.00000000, 1000.00000000, 1000.00000000 ],
        [ 1000.00000000, 1000.00000000, 1000.00000000 ],
        [ 1000.00000000, 1000.00000000, 1000.00000000 ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write it to a json file, and moreover, I hope the text is aligned exactly in the way I write it above.

However, if I write it using the following code (`d` is the dictionary)

```
>>> d
{u'A': {u'B': {u'C': [[1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0], [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0], [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0]]}}}
>>> json.dump(d,open('b.json','w'))
```

What I get in `b.json` is as follows:

```
{"A": {"B": {"C": [[1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0], [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0], [1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0]]}}}
```

All the contents stay in one line.

Then I try the following way:

```
json.dump(d,open('b.json','w'), indent=2)
```

The contents now become:

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "C": [
        [
          1000.0, 
          1000.0, 
          1000.0
        ], 
        [
          1000.0, 
          1000.0, 
          1000.0
        ], 
        [
          1000.0, 
          1000.0, 
          1000.0
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Both alignments are ugly. Is there a way for me to achieve the ideal alignment?

Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Not unless you seriously customise your JSON encoder. Aesthetics are subjective, and there's no way to account for that in a generic encoder. You can either have it indented or not, you can't have it indented in a specific custom way.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `dump` with `indent`, you can use the builtin pretty-print module.

```
import pprint
pprint.print(json)
```